# How can I have one LED go on, when another goes off

Tags: switches, relay, switching

I have a scenario where when one switched electrical path for example a tail light (LED #2) on a motorcycle is switched off, I want LED #1 to go on. When power is switched on to LED #2, then ground for LED #1 should be disconnected to shut the LED #1 off. So basically when the positive line for LED #2 becomes charged (turned on) I want to disconnect the ground or positive connection for LED #1 so it shuts off.

[image: What would I put where the "?" mark is, a relay?]

Thank you everyone for the help! Based on your feedback I think this diagram would work. LED #1 only turns on if LED #2 is off, correct? [image]

Comment: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar with real electrical symbols on it including switches, relays, LEDs, batteries and earth/ground. It's very easy to use. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Thanks, thats good to know :). As you can tell my schematic drawing is at an elementary level at best.

Comment: Your drawing is sufficient. No need to complicate things.

Comment: As to if that's correct, yes. That's exactly how it should be wired. If you use bare leds and no a led+resistor or led+current limit circuit module, then you need that as well.

Comment: Great thanks Passerby, yes I have resistors for the LEDs

Comment: @Passerby: I completely understand your comment but I struggled to understand the diagrams. Using the proper symbols might have helped the OP figure out for him/herself as there are defined connection points for the coils and contacts.

Comment: Struggled? Really? I'm not even going to respond to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular spst relay would do what you want. It would have to be a normally closed type. A spdt or dpdt relay would work as well, ignoring the extra connectors.

Comment: I am struggling to understand how a SPST switch would work in this application. could you please explain?

Comment: @rjoshi it wouldn't. A spst normally closed relay would. A relay and a switch arnt the same thing.

Comment: I see. So one LED would be on the activating coil and the other on the "output" the relay?

Comment: Yes. Exactly like OP shows in his second picture. Just ignore the N.O. contact on a SPDT relay.

Answer (score 2):

Single-Pole-Double-Throw (SPDT) Switch, of the On-On Variant. You can also get On-Off-On which keep both LEDs off in the middle position.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpe9kh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: While this is completely valid, it depends on if OP can modify or replace the switch. A motorcycle turn signal switch isn't easily replaced with a different mechanism type.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a basic SPDT (Single Pole Double Throw) switch or relay.